# Xdebug not working with "Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections"

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying to get Xdebug to work with "Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections". It's working just fine if I use the "Debug " button. But I don't want to use that since it's inconvenient.

I'm using PhpStorm.

I'm using PHP 7.4 "php-7.4.32-Win32-vc15-x64" and Apache "httpd-2.4.54-win64-VS16" along with [Laragon](https://laragon.org/index.html) (Laragon, not Laravel, they're 2 different unrelated things).

I have the following settings in `php.ini`

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension = xdebug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.mode = trace, debug
xdebug.log="C:/laragon/logs/xdebug.log"
xdebug.discover_client_host=true
xdebug.client_discovery_header = "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR,REMOTE_ADDR"
```

I checked the logs and Xdebug does indeed try to connect to 127.0.0.1 on port 9003

```
[16928] [Step Debug] INFO: Client host discovered through HTTP header, connecting to 127.0.0.1:9003.
[16928] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 127.0.0.1:9003 (from REMOTE_ADDR HTTP header). :-)
```

I have the [Chrome Xdebug extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc) installed. I chose to use the `PHPSTORM` cookie. I checked if the cookies are sent and they are in fact sent and arrive just fine.

I have created a debug connection (see the screenshot below). I have also tried using `localhost`, `omsbs.test`, and `http://omsbs.test/` as a host with no success.

[image]

I checked the `hosts` file(I'm on windows) and it seems to be fine

```text
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost

127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1      omsbs.test           #laragon magic!
```

I'm completely out of ideas as to what's wrong.

Comment: I would remove the config in PhpStorm under "PHP Remote Debug" — PhpStorm should ask upon an unknown connection as to what to do with it. I would also turn on "Break at first line" (in the Debug/Run menu) to see that a connection is made and PhpStorm accepted it.

Comment: *"I have created a debug connection (see the screenshot below). I have also tried using `localhost`, `omsbs.test`, and `http://omsbs.test/` as a host with no success."* Delete that Servers entry and try to debug -- the IDE will offer to create one for you when it will get a debug connection. In your existing one you may have entered the wrong info (e.g. IDE may see different host than what you think it should use) ... or missing path mappings. P.S. I hope you understand the difference between "host" and "URL" .. because `http://omsbs.test/` is a URL...